# How can I disable the "/" preset on a href link so that it does not add a full external URL to the site link when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, function, url, button, href

I'm trying to change a button from directing to an internal link ('/page') to an external URL

Here is an example of what I'm looking at:

```
    const buttonsOne = [
       { to: '/page1', text: 'FOR USERS' }, 
       { to: '/page2', text: 'FOR VENDORS', rounded: true }
     ]
```

Here's what I've tried with one of the buttons:

```
     const buttonsTwo = [
        { to: href="https://example.com", text: 'LEARN MORE' }
      ]
```

Every time it opens now, it opens like this resulting in a 404:
"https://example.com/https://example.com/"

How can I make the default "/" stop so it goes to the external URL?

Thank you!!

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might need to improve your question with the specific JS code that you are trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to disable the "/", you can't link the button that way. That's because buttons can't handle external links. (At least to my knowledge)
The way to get around this is to wrap the button with an  tag

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank"><button>Wewew</button></a>
```

target="_blank" opens the link in a new page.